# What is the benefit of accessing Amazon Redshift from SQL Server Management?

Tags: amazon-redshift, ssms, data-analysis

I have seen a video on YouTube about accessing data in `Amazon Redshift` from `SSMS`. Could someone tell me how this will benefit me in terms of money and performance? Is this feasible or is there any disadvantage in accessing data stored in the `Redshift` from `SSMS` and performing queries and analysis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSMS is an SQL client & like any other SQL client, it forwards on the SQL queries that *you* write. Your queries affect the cost & performance of your database solution, not the SQL client.

There's no disadvantage or advantage, it's your choice which SQL client to use if any.